# creating jQuery dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

can anyone assist me on how to write a jquery that checks two drop down list inputs and determines the third dropdown from the database. I have tried different methods from the web including jCombo but doesn't seem to lead me anywhere. I will appreciate an illustrated line of code

Comment: Your question is rather vague, but it seems like all you need is some sort of Ajax script.

Comment: barmar 2 I understand that but am stuck. with the almost zero experience in jQuery. thats all I can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Try this:

**Index Page**

```
<select id="opt1" onchange="change()"><option value="1">Test1</option><option value="2">Test2</option></select>

<select id="opt2" onchange="change()"><option value="1">Test1</option><option value="2">Test2</option></select>


<select id="opt3"></select>

<script  type="text/javascript">
function change() {
var e = document.getElementById("opt1");
var t1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var s = document.getElementById("opt2");
var t2 = e.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

$.post("/sample.php", {t1:t1, t2:t2 },
   function(data) {
      document.getElementById("opt3").innerHTML = data;  
   });

} 
</script>
```

**Sample.php**

```
<?php
$t1 = $_POST["t1"];
$t2 = $_POST["t2"];

// make your own condition

echo  '<option>Success</option>';
?>
```

I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this post](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/) but with two selects to populate another one?

Comment: yap that's what am asking...thanks let me try the code ASAP ..will get back to you